# heroku : at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout"

Tags: node.js, heroku

this my first project in node js and it worked on localhost but when deployed on Heroku i got some errors that appears application error , below is my code and `heroku logs` . can somebody please help me in this? i can't figure out where is the problem since i tried all possible solutions and it didn't work

thanks in advance

```html
2021-12-09T19:50:00.133986+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-12-09T19:50:00.134003+00:00 app[web.1]: > api-master-nodejs@1.0.0 start /app
2021-12-09T19:50:00.134003+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2021-12-09T19:50:00.134003+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T19:50:01.187253+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-09T19:50:32.260199+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=obscure-waters-05043.herokuapp.com request_id=cfbf2688-d4d4-4b7a-adf0-2663a1d7dace fwd="85.108.198.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-12-09T19:50:43.082048+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-12-09T19:50:43.107251+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-12-09T19:50:43.871385+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-12-09T19:50:44.069113+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obscure-waters-05043.herokuapp.com request_id=49445fee-a0d0-4199-9adb-bf4314016e98 fwd="85.108.198.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11418ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-12-09T19:50:44.193647+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-12-09T19:50:45.155711+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-12-09T19:50:46.561346+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T19:50:46.561360+00:00 app[web.1]: > api-master-nodejs@1.0.0 start /app
2021-12-09T19:50:46.561361+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2021-12-09T19:50:46.561361+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T19:50:47.295414+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-09T19:51:51.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user sebaalchalabi@gmail.com
2021-12-09T19:52:08.296910+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 202801b6 by user sebaalchalabi@gmail.com
2021-12-09T19:52:08.296910+00:00 app[api]: Release v44 created by user sebaalchalabi@gmail.com
2021-12-09T19:52:08.590301+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-12-09T19:52:08.615504+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-12-09T19:52:09.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-12-09T19:52:09.331866+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-12-09T19:52:09.574745+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-12-09T19:52:10.680588+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-12-09T19:52:11.875404+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T19:52:11.875420+00:00 app[web.1]: > api-master-nodejs@1.0.0 start /app
2021-12-09T19:52:11.875420+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2021-12-09T19:52:11.875420+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T19:52:12.491955+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-09T19:53:21.013488+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=obscure-waters-05043.herokuapp.com request_id=3d66d37c-eec6-44d2-8792-a7ddff579766 fwd="85.108.198.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-12-09T19:53:41.188552+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-12-09T19:53:41.191420+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-12-09T19:53:41.978236+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-12-09T19:53:42.180105+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obscure-waters-05043.herokuapp.com request_id=98bb6ae6-b3ec-4206-95a4-6279e7aff78b fwd="85.108.198.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=20953ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-12-09T19:53:42.314257+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-12-09T19:53:43.672529+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-12-09T19:53:45.699311+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T19:53:45.699323+00:00 app[web.1]: > api-master-nodejs@1.0.0 start /app
2021-12-09T19:53:45.699324+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2021-12-09T19:53:45.699324+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T19:53:47.034852+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-09T19:57:01.713660+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-12-09T19:57:01.847677+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-12-09T19:57:02.852486+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-12-09T19:57:03.172988+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-12-09T19:57:04.132727+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-12-09T19:57:05.215604+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T19:57:05.215618+00:00 app[web.1]: > api-master-nodejs@1.0.0 start /app
2021-12-09T19:57:05.215618+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2021-12-09T19:57:05.215618+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T19:57:05.821299+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-09T19:57:15.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user sebaalchalabi@gmail.com
2021-12-09T19:57:30.843649+00:00 app[api]: Release v45 created by user sebaalchalabi@gmail.com
2021-12-09T19:57:30.843649+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 338ae6f5 by user sebaalchalabi@gmail.com
2021-12-09T19:57:31.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-12-09T19:57:31.085978+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-12-09T19:57:31.201283+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-12-09T19:57:31.880715+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-12-09T19:57:32.065101+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-12-09T19:57:33.428958+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-12-09T19:57:34.677151+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T19:57:34.677180+00:00 app[web.1]: > api-master-nodejs@1.0.0 start /app
2021-12-09T19:57:34.677181+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2021-12-09T19:57:34.677181+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T19:57:35.761777+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-09T19:58:08.215698+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=obscure-waters-05043.herokuapp.com request_id=51f7029d-58a6-445a-a111-a77bccfa90c0 fwd="85.108.198.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-12-09T19:58:38.614677+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obscure-waters-05043.herokuapp.com request_id=56500d70-9535-4cdf-8665-2cfe463b908d fwd="85.108.198.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30002ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-12-09T20:05:25.879914+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=obscure-waters-05043.herokuapp.com request_id=e7ff010a-b9b7-49e8-bae6-b72eb0794c0e fwd="34.204.52.120" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
2021-12-09T20:07:18.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user sebaalchalabi@gmail.com
2021-12-09T20:07:34.550502+00:00 app[api]: Release v46 created by user sebaalchalabi@gmail.com
2021-12-09T20:07:34.550502+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 274eee09 by user sebaalchalabi@gmail.com
2021-12-09T20:07:35.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-12-09T20:07:38.124510+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-12-09T20:07:38.227065+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-12-09T20:07:39.027871+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-12-09T20:07:39.245964+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-12-09T20:07:40.890971+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-12-09T20:07:42.140238+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T20:07:42.140265+00:00 app[web.1]: > api-master-nodejs@1.0.0 start /app
2021-12-09T20:07:42.140265+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2021-12-09T20:07:42.140266+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T20:07:43.221265+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-09T20:08:14.814637+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=obscure-waters-05043.herokuapp.com request_id=afc72089-87b7-4d01-a2dd-a0efddfc3d62 fwd="85.108.198.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-12-09T20:08:45.157453+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obscure-waters-05043.herokuapp.com request_id=b38528cf-d42d-4184-b52b-6808444e99bd fwd="85.108.198.36" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-12-09T20:13:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user sebaalchalabi@gmail.com
2021-12-09T20:14:15.262368+00:00 app[api]: Deploy fe24fd44 by user sebaalchalabi@gmail.com
2021-12-09T20:14:15.262368+00:00 app[api]: Release v47 created by user sebaalchalabi@gmail.com
2021-12-09T20:14:15.498236+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-12-09T20:14:15.523576+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-12-09T20:14:16.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-12-09T20:14:16.770111+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-12-09T20:14:17.043608+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-12-09T20:14:17.959793+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-12-09T20:14:19.191029+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T20:14:19.191041+00:00 app[web.1]: > api-master-nodejs@1.0.0 start /app
2021-12-09T20:14:19.191041+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2021-12-09T20:14:19.191042+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-09T20:14:19.891841+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

app.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const http = require('http');
const multer = require("multer");
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);



// corsfffffffff



/************************************** Socket IO Related Start ************************************************/

// config dotenv
dotenv.config();


const dbURI = process.env.MONGO_URL || "mongodb+srv://user:cvcvcv00S-@cluster0.jpij0.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
mongoose.connect(dbURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(result => server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000) )
 
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.json);


// app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.path = req.path;
  next();
});

const subscribersRouter = require('./routes/subscribers')
app.use('/subscribers', subscribersRouter)
app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.send("welcome to app");
})

// const ping = () => request('https://obscure-waters-05043.herokuapp.com/', (error, response, body) => {
//     console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
//     console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
//     console.log('body:', body); // Print body of response received
// });
```

package.json

```html
{
  "name": "api-master-nodejs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "http": "0.0.1-security",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.14",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.3",
    "require": "^2.4.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^5.2.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: My guess is it's an issue inside the `subscribers` routes. This is the error that happens when your Heroku server gives no response after an endpoint is called. Since you don't have much in the app yet, you could try spinning up the app with https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html to give yourself a little bit better boiler plate.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. All i to do was just hit the restart all dynos link
[image: restart all dynos link]

Comment: I'm having similar problem and tried this solution, but it didn't help at all.. Running out of ideas now.